# To get mobile network timezone in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios6

Currently I am developing an application for global wide customers and facing an issue in TimeZone. So, Here is a requirement like to get my current network(Where I am receiving SIM signals-) timezone and set into device programmatically.

This should be happen to every time navigate to one screen to another screen. Here, I am really stuck on this to get my network time zone. Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, Apple has not opened up any API for accessing low level network detail or sim card access.

You will have to use [`NSTimeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html)